# How to convert varchar time to 24hours Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My table has a `VARCHAR` column which contains time records. Record look like below:

```
TXN_TIME
--------
053124
173932
011815
120349
134207
```

I need to convert it

```
TXN_TIME
--------
05:31:24:000000
17:39:32:000000
01:18:15:000000
12:03:49:000000
13:42:07:000000
```

Comment: use `SUBSTRING`

Comment: What have ***YOU*** tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: substring combined with concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear whether you want your result as a `VARCHAR` or an actual `TIME` type, so here's both:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    TXN_TIME VARCHAR(6)
)

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT '053124'
UNION
SELECT '173932'
UNION
SELECT '011815'
UNION
SELECT '120349'
UNION
SELECT '134207'

SELECT  TXN_TIME,
        LEFT(TXN_TIME,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(TXN_TIME,3,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(TXN_TIME,5,2) + ':000000' AS Converted,
        CONVERT(TIME(6),LEFT(TXN_TIME,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(TXN_TIME,3,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(TXN_TIME,5,2)) AS ConvertedTime
FROM @Table
```

Results:

```
/----------------------------------------------\
| TXN_TIME |    Converted    |  ConvertedTime  |
|----------+-----------------+-----------------|
|  011815  | 01:18:15:000000 | 01:18:15.000000 |
|  053124  | 05:31:24:000000 | 05:31:24.000000 |
|  120349  | 12:03:49:000000 | 12:03:49.000000 |
|  134207  | 13:42:07:000000 | 13:42:07.000000 |
|  173932  | 17:39:32:000000 | 17:39:32.000000 |
\----------------------------------------------/
```